# Retrieving git branch name in prompt or Android gradle: on Jenkins it returns HEAD

Tags: jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, command-prompt, git-branch

In gradle I'd like to add both the current branch-name and commit-number as suffix to my versionName. (Why? Because when I build my app in Jenkins to release it in HockeyApp, it's useful to show what branch & commit that app was built from!)

So when I enter this in command prompt, my current branch name is returned:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Same happens when I use this line in Android gradle, using the code in either [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760102/2660216) answer, or as shown in this piece of gradle code:

```
def getVersionNameSuffix = { ->

    def branch = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        // The command line to request the current branch:
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = branch
    }
    println "My current branch: " + branch
    def versionNameSuffix = "-" + branch

    // ... some other suffix additions ...

    return versionNameSuffix
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        versionNameSuffix getVersionNameSuffix()
    }
}
```

Resulting log (this is exactly what I want):

> "My current branch: feature/MyFeature"

However, when I build my app in a Jenkins job, it will output a different result:

> "My current branch: HEAD"

Why does this happen, and how to correctly retrieve my current branch name in Jenkins?

**EDIT:**

I've used a different approach, which returns the branchName correctly in most cases, also on Jenkins:

```
git name-rev --name-only HEAD
```

Example output in prompt:

> "My current branch: feature/MyFeature"

Example output in Jenkins:

> "My current branch: remotes/origin/feature/MyFeature"

I can remove "remotes/origin/" if i like, so that's okay!

But this approach causes different trouble (both in prompt, gradle and on Jenkins). When I have tagged the last commit, it won't output the branch-name, but this:

> "My current branch: tags/MyTag^0"

**EDIT 2:**

A third approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245587/2660216).

Including the comments below the answer, I could use *grep **  to retrieve the branch in prompt. However, I cannot use the backslash in the gradle code. This fails:

```
commandLine 'git', 'branch', '|', 'grep', '\\*'
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try the env: BRANCH_NAME

```
BRANCH_NAME 
    For a multibranch project, this will be set to the name of the branch being built, for example in case you wish to deploy to production from master but not from feature branches.
```

Access it with env.BRANCH_NAME

Comment: I can use 'env.' in build.gradle, but cannot use env.BRANCH_NAME. I am able to access env.BRANCH_NAME in the JenkinsFile, so I can use it as a parameter for a pipeline or Jenkins job, but guess that won't help. I need it in build.gradle.

Comment: try "$System.env.BRANCH_NAME"

Comment: That doesn't work either, have you been able to use that command in build.gradle in the App (or mobile) module? If so: where did you define it then?