# What is best way in Gradle to deal with git data

Tags: git, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

Seems like

1. [gradle-git plugin](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) is no more maintained so `GitBranchList` api will not available with `Gradle-6.6.1`

```
task getBranchName(type: GitBranchList) << {
   print getWorkingBranch().name
}
```

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760102/1665592 ... it fails on CI tools(Jenkins) if gradle wrapper isn't invoked from root of project where `.git` dir is. It produces error `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` as `Gradle Wrapper` is invoked by Jenkins Gradle plugin from outside of dir where `.git` folder resides.

```
def gitBranch() {
    def branch = ""
    def proc = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD".execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> branch = line }
    proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.waitFor()
    branch
}
```

Both solutions doesn't work well to detect current git branch using Gradle..

How, can I get branch name properly

Comment: I used https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit recently

Comment: You might be using lower versions of Gradle. 6.6.1 won't allowed me to use grgit plugin. Since, that project isn't maintained anymore I found it not a good idea to use those API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out as

```
/*
   Gets the HEAD git commit for the module.
   Use git to find the hash tag and format a date into YYYYMMDD-hhmmss format.
 */
def getGitCommitHash() {
    def gitFolder = "${project.projectDir}/.git/"
    def takeFromHash = 12
    def head = new File(gitFolder + "HEAD").text.split(":")
    def isCommit = head.length == 1
    if (isCommit) return head[0].trim().take(takeFromHash)
    def refHead = new File(gitFolder + head[1].trim())
    refHead.text.trim().take takeFromHash
}

/*
   Use git to find the current branch name
 */
def getGitBranch() {
    def gitBranch = "Unknown branch"
    try {
        def workingDir = new File("${project.projectDir}/.git/")
        def result = 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'.execute(null, workingDir)
        result.waitFor()
        if (result.exitValue() == 0) {
            gitBranch = result.text.trim()
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }
    return gitBranch
}
```